# Python sorted plot

Tags: python, sorting, plot, bar-chart, seaborn

I want to use seaborn to perform a `sns.barplot` where the values are ordered e.g. in ascending order.

In case the `order` parameter of seaborn is set the plot seems to duplicate the labels for all non-NaN labels.

Trying to pre-sort the values like `mydf.sort_values(['myValueField'], ascending=False)` does not change the result as seaborn does not seem to interpret it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you save the changes by `pd.sort_values`? If not, probably you have to add the `inplace` keyword:

`mydf.sort_values(['myValueField'], ascending=False, inplace=True)`

Comment: indeed that was missing. I tried that before, but there must have been a problem with jupyter picking up these (external) changes. Thanks.